# Something like SlackTextViewController for android

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, tags, tokenize

Do someone know some lib like: https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController

but for android ?

its input box that can use with tags (@) hashtags (#) with auto complete and tokenize in addition to free text.
very useful for comments and messages.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try looking here http://android-arsenal.com ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried and i didn't find something good.

Comment: I think you can play with and tweak a RecyclerView to do just the same